# How do you provide defaults to powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script such as the following:

```
param([parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$sourceFolder)

write-host $sourceFolder
```

How do I provide a default value for the `$sourceFolder` parameter such that the parameter becomes optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH! Just figured it out....

```
param([string]$sourceFolder = "1234")
```

Comment: @AdiInbar I think you misread - Andy wrote 'Note - need' not 'No - need'.

Comment: @Plymouth223 Heh, you're right - I read that as "Note - no need to remove the mandatory restriction." I guess that's a sign that it's time to go to bed!